# MutableList clear() and addAll() behaves strangely

Tags: java, android, kotlin, baseadapter

Basically I'm using a method inside of a `BaseAdapter` to refresh it. It actually worked for plenty functions, however once I tried to implement a new one and used this its custom method to refresh it, it just cleared control `MutableList`. The control MutableList and the MutableList I'm passing throught the method is the same, however I highly doubt Kotlin would keep reference that deep. So I ended up placing logs everywhere and foud out, that the `.clear()` call cleared even the `MutableList` I'm passing. Tried even re initializating the `MutableList` itself before I'm passing it, so there is no chance of any sort of reference. 
So I guess I'm asking if `.clear()` method is normally used or is it something that actually doesn't as it should be.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it hard just use this code and let it go

```
fun updateData(list :MutableList<MarketOffer>){
    this.itemsListAdapter = list
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"The control MutableList and the MutableList I'm passing throught the method is the same, however I highly doubt Kotlin would keep reference that deep".

It does keep the reference that deep. Reference will always point to the instance no matter where it is in the program.

If you don't want to affect the input list. Then you should copy the list content.

I'm assuming you have a method that does this line.

```
fun setList(list: MutableList<MarketOffer>) {
    this.itemsListAdapter = list // points to the same instance of MutableList
}
```

Use this line instead

```
fun setList(list: MutableList<MarketOffer>) {
    this.itemsListAdapter = list.toMutableList() // create a new instance of MutableList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data list inside your adapter is a reference of your original data.
So if you clear it, means clear your original list.

If you don't want that, you can try to create a `listOriginal` and `listDisplay` to manipulate them separately. And remember do not use `listDisplay = listOriginal` directly, that makes them hold same ref again.

Comment: The strange thing was,  that it's exactly what I tried afterward and neither that worked. Which is pretty much the only reason I posted this "dumb" question, it's not really about the problem itself, more about the behaviour I didnt expect it to do.